# "The application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer" - Cpp

Tags: c++, bittorrent

I am trying to delete a buffer in a function using Cpp,
This is my code so far:

```
void GetPiece(int size)
{
    //std::cout << "Downloading File Index: " + currFileIndex <<  " More: " + pieceSize - size;
    char * newBuffer = new char[size];
    bitRequest->RecvBySize(newBuffer, size - 4, 5);
    //newBuffer += 8;
    File file("work_torrent.mp3");
    file.WriteToFile(newBuffer + 8, size - 4);
    file.Close();



    pieceSize -= size -4;
    std::cout << "Downloading File Index: " << currFileIndex << " More: " << pieceSize << std::endl;

    if (pieceSize <= 0)
    {
        currFileIndex++;
        pieceSize = pieces.at(currFileIndex).fileSize;
    }

    offset += size - 4;

    if (pieceSize > 16384)
    {
        if (1048576 - offset < 16384)
        {
            requestSize = 1048576 - offset;
            if (requestSize == 0)
            {
                offset = 0;
                currPieceIndex++;
                if (pieceSize > 16384)
                {
                    requestSize = 16384;
                }
                else {
                    requestSize = pieceSize;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            requestSize = 16384;
        }

    }
    else {
        requestSize = pieceSize;
    }



    bitRequest->RequestPiece(currPieceIndex, offset, requestSize);


    delete[] newBuffer; // Here it throws the error


}
```

The error:

[image]

It appears only when I am trying to free the char array from memmorry, Someone know why it gives the error?

When the delete line is not there, after some times that I call to the function the program crash due to fail allocation.

Comment: `file.WriteToFile(newBuffer + 8, size - 4);` When passing to `WriteFile`, you have moved the buffer pointer forward by 8 bytes, while stating that size is smaller by 4 bytes. It is possible that `WriteToFile` read 4 bytes past the end of the buffer. Can't tell what wrote past the end of the buffer without [mcve].

Comment: What does `bitRequest->RecvBySize(newBuffer, size - 4, 5);` do?

Comment: @NathanOliver Recieve data by size to a specific buffer.

Comment: @Y.Franco And, why didn't you think it was important to show us that function, if it **writes** to the buffer, and you are getting an error about **writing** past the end of the buffer?

Comment: The crash is likely due to undefined behaviour in some part of your program. The mcve will help you - or us - find it.

Comment: Also, `pieceSize` is not declared or initialized anywhere.

Comment: @Y.Franco `RecvBySize` has two integer parameters. Which one is the size, and what is the other one?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius was right, Thanks! The problem was that the writeToFile function wrote 4 bytes more then the buffer size. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you modified the element outside of the array boundary. You know, in C++ the IDE won't check if the element you are assigning to is outside or within.

Comment: While this might be the answer to the question, I'd personally put these kinds of "I guess" answers first as comments in the question's comment section to ask for clarification. That way- if the guess is wrong, there's less answer noise.